# Why the safety of airplanes have not been developed long time ago?

Tags: safety

I have a question about the safety of airplanes.

since I was a kid the first time I flight by airplane they have the safety which is a belt and yellow thing that puts into your mouth when a problem happens. If we notice today we still have the same safety and everything is almost the same except the way they show you the safety so today we have screen in front of seats which shows how to do safety by video tape.

Now, what I want to know "why don't we improve the safety since that time like 20 years ago from now for example?"

If you say there is no way to improve safety I will tell you a hint about improving the safety of people when they are in the air and things is getting worse (we can think more to get more ideas about improving the safety of airplanes).

- We can put in every seat or every 6 seats a paragliding emergency where if there is something happens to airplane and it goes down, then we can rescue the life of people. You can argue with me about how to do it but it is for sure necessary to put paragliding tools in every airplane we have in order to prevent the death of airplane accident, especially as the number of airplane accident is increasing, the death of people is increasing.

Don't agree with me that we need to improve the safety of airplanes to save people life. In these days, I always hear that airbus announces a new model of their airplane, but they only improve it to earn more money by putting more seats and using less oil!!

I hope to find someone specialliest in this airbus or any airplane and tell us why we still see the same safety that was in 20 years ago?!

Comment: The most effective way to improve safety in airplanes is not to load them up with equipment to be used in case of a crash (which often no concievable safety equipment could make survivable), but to make them more reliable, so they crash less often.  I believe a look at fatalites per million passenger miles will show this has been done.

Comment: Most safety improvements are things that passengers never see, a majority of it being crew training, and other things like structural changes. Even the design of the seat, materials used, fuel tanks, etc have all been greatly improved over the years, stuff that you wouldn't notice. The reason a seat-belt and oxygen mask are still used is that they are still effective, and supplement other safety measures.

Comment: By the way: *"as the number of airplane accident is increasing, the death of people is increasing."* is completely false. It is true that a single accident may kill more people (larger aircraft), but the number of incidents is going down year-over-year since the early 80's. Flying is safer than ever. Most of what kills people in crashes isn't the crash, its the fire afterwards...

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes, you are right, if they improve the crew training, then we have a high probability that airplane accident would be decreasing. I did not see this point. Thank you for your two helpful comments! Completely agree with you!

Comment: Can you provide proof for your claim that safety hasn't improved in the last 20 years? I'm pretty sure that there have been dozens of advisories, reports, suggestions, recommendations, ADs, etc. by the relevant authorities in that time frame, plus improvements the manufacturers made by themselves without being prompted or forced by the authorities, plus improvements in reliability, plus improvements in training, plus improvements in procedures, and many, many, many things more.

Comment: For example, as a result of the Überlingen Mid-Air Collision of 2002 (so, well within your 20-year time frame), 2 changes were made: 1) a strict policy that pilots should *always* follow TCAS RAs and ignore ATC, 2) development of a new TCAS version which is currently being phased in, that is able to reverse an RA if it detects that the other aircraft is ignoring *its* RA. There were also changes being made that ensure that there are always at least 2 controllers in the control room at all times. So, that's two improvements to safety procedures and one improvement to safety software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We can put in [...] a paragliding emergency where if there is something happens to airplane and it goes down, then we can rescue the life of people.

There are some conditions in Air liners that prevent the save use of a parachute:

- Height

  - atmosphere pressure
    Air Liners cruse in heights where the atmosphere is so thin that you can't  get enough oxygen by normal breathing.  For this reason the planes cabin is under pressure. in consequence it is not possible to open the windows as escape.
  - Operating the parachute
    Even if that was possible you have to fasten your self in the parachute harness. This is (depending on the  harness structure) difficult for an untrained person when standing on solid ground and IMHO impossible in free fall.
  - anoxia
    You might blackout bye anoxia before fixed yourself in the parachutes harness.
- Speed

  Airliners cruse at `800+km/h` (relative to the surrounding air). That means that you get decelerated by approximately `800km/h` as soon as you leave the aircraft. This exposes you to huge forces resulting in serious injuries.
- Landing a Parachute

  Landing a parachute is dangerous for many reasons. In easy cases you fall into flat ground where you ma get minor injuries like a broken leg or similar. 
  But imaging to fall into a big tree, a lake or into rocky setting?  Do you think an untrained person can survive this without serious threads for her live?
- Dangerous flight phases

  Parachutes will only be useful above a *minimum height*. This minimum height does not only depend on the parachutes technical parameters but also on the time to get one, put it on and leaving the air plane for the *slowest passenger*. But the most accidents with fatalities happened during start or landing where was not time to leave the plane.
- Likeliness of Survival

  History shows that most accidents happening in the air can be handled by the crew and the plane can be landed (more or less) safely as long as it is in "one piece".

  If the plane breaks into pieces in the air this usually  happens in a kind of "blow up" so that there is not time to look for a parachute and put it on.

---

So after all: No, having a parachute for each passenger will not improve their safety, it will only increase the overall weight of the plane.

Comment: I agree with what you said and I understand the results of using emergency parachute. I hope in future we have a physical things to save people life. Thank you for your answer! It is very informative!

Comment: 800 km/h isn't a deceleration, it's a velocity.

Comment: What I meant is that the difference in speed is approximately 800km/h. I'm not a native speaker but I think that the sentence can be understood this way.